# xcode view became modal when connected as segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm pretty new to Swift/xCode and now I'm stuck with a very (for me) strange behaviour. When I connect a button inside a view to perform a segue, the target view became modal.. what I'm doing wrong?
Please take a look to below gif that show the problem and my setup

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why some one vote -1 ? i did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoginViewController` should be managed by a `NavigationController` to make it work. If you try to `show` some view controller without having a `NavigationController` in the navigation flow, it will appear as a `modal`. So embed `LoginViewController` as the **`RootViewController`** of a `NavigationViewController`